# ¿Cómo guardar firma digital en android studio retrofit asp.net web api a SQL Server?

Tags: android-studio, asp.net-mvc, retrofit

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo registrar una firma(firmaDigital) desde `android studio` a `SQL Server`. Para ello he creado un web api que me permita registrar en sql Server mediante `retrofit`. Pero tengo problemas al enviar los datos en retrofit por que envía el valor del atributo firmaDigital como nulo al webapi y no encuentro una solución de porque no coge el valor.

Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar ya que no encuentro una solución al problema del porque envia nulo el atributo firmaDigital en retrofit.

El webapi fue generado con Entity Data Model.

SQL Server

```
create table Firma
(
idFirma int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
firmaDigital image
)
```

ApiController(ASP.NET MVC C#)

```
// POST: api/Firmas
[ResponseType(typeof(Firma))]
public IHttpActionResult PostFirma([FromBody] Firma firma)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Firmas.Add(firma);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = firma.idFirma }, firma);
}
```

Método para obtener la Firma

```
public class CaptureBitmapView extends View {

    private Bitmap _Bitmap;
    private Canvas _Canvas;
    private Path _Path;
    private Paint _BitmapPaint;
    private Paint _paint;
    private float _mX;
    private float _mY;
    private float TouchTolerance = 4;
    private float LineThickness = 4;

    public CaptureBitmapView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _Path = new Path();
        _BitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        _paint = new Paint();
        _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        _paint.setDither(true);
        _paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,0));
        _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        _paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        _paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        _paint.setStrokeWidth(LineThickness);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        _Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,(h>0?h:((View) this.getParent()).getHeight()),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        _Canvas = new Canvas(_Bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255,237,239,250));
        canvas.drawBitmap(_Bitmap,0,0,_BitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(_Path,_paint);
    }

    private void TouchStart(float x,float y){
        _Path.reset();
        _Path.moveTo(x,y);
        _mX = x;
        _mY = y;
    }

    private void TouchMove(float x, float y){
        float dx = Math.abs(x-_mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y-_mY);

        if(dx >= TouchTolerance || dy >= TouchTolerance){
            _Path.quadTo(_mX,_mY,(x+_mX)/2,(y+_mY)/2);
            _mX = x;
            _mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void TouchUp(){
        if(!_Path.isEmpty()){
            _Path.lineTo(_mX,_mY);
            _Canvas.drawPath(_Path,_paint);
        }else {
            _Canvas.drawPoint(_mX,_mY,_paint);
        }
        _Path.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                TouchStart(x,y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                TouchMove(x,y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                TouchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void ClearCanvas(){
        _Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        //_Canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255,237,239,250));
        invalidate();
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
    public byte[] getBytes(){
        Bitmap b = getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        View v = (View) this.getParent();
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(v.getLeft(),v.getTop(),v.getRight(),v.getBottom());
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }
}
```

FirmaActivity

```
public class FirmaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String url = Constantes.URL;
    private MaterialButton btnGuardarFirma,btnBorrarFirma,btnSalirFirma;
    private CaptureBitmapView mSig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firma);

        btnGuardarFirma = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarFirma);
        btnGuardarFirma.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnBorrarFirma = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrarFirma);
        btnBorrarFirma.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSalirFirma = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSalirFirma);
        btnSalirFirma.setOnClickListener(this);

        LinearLayout mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.signLayout);
        mSig = new CaptureBitmapView(this,null);
        mContent.addView(mSig,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnGuardarFirma:
                registrarFirma();
                break;
            case R.id.btnBorrarFirma:
                borrarFirma();
                break;
            case R.id.btnSalirFirma:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registrarFirma() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        IFirmaService service = retrofit.create(IFirmaService.class);

        Firma firma = new Firma();
        firma.setFirmaDigital(mSig.getBytes());

        Call<Firma> call = service.createFirma(firma);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Firma>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Firma> call, Response<Firma> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se registro correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Firma> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e( "Error: ",t.getMessage() );
            }
        });

    }

    private void borrarFirma(){
        mSig.ClearCanvas();
    }
}
```

Interfaz Retrofit

```
@POST("Firmas")
    Call<Firma> createFirma(@Body Firma firma);
```

Para obtener la firma lo obtuve del siguiente enlace esta tal cual
https://www.natapuntes.es/capturar-firma-manual-android/

Comment: No dupliques las preguntas. En la anterior se te preguntó si en ambas partes, en la clase Java y la API , la propiedad `firmaDigital` se llama igual. No confirmaste eso y es importante porque es una posible causa.

Comment: no es lo misma pregunta, en una pregunto que tipo de dato debo declarar cuando es de tipo image en android y en la segunda pregunto porque en retrofit me envia el valor de firmaDigital nulo

Comment: aparte de ello respondí a tu comentario diciendo que era bytes.

Comment: No me respondiste a mi pero no importa. No me refiero al tipo de la variable sino al nombre `firmaDigital` tanto en la clase Java como en la API deben tener el mismo nombre. Si una está mal escrita puede ser el motivo por el cual el arreglo no encuentra en la API.

Comment: Son iguales tanto en Android y webapi en tipo de dato y nombres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar de otra forma que sería convertir el arreglo de bytes a una cadena en formato base 64.

Para eso en la clase Java cambia la propiedad `firmaDigital` para que sea un String.

```
class Firma{
   public int idFirma;
   public String firmaDigital;
}
```

Para convertir el arreglo  a base 64 usa el siguiente código:

```
Firma firma = new Firma();

firma.imagenDigital = Base64.encodeToString(mSig.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

En la API agrega una nueva clase llamada `FirmaModel` con la siguiente estructura:

```
public class FirmaModel{

  public int IdFirma {get;set;}
  public string FirmaDigital {get;set;}

}
```

Y modifica la acción para recibir un parámetro de tipo `FirmaModel`, dentro de la acción se convertirá la cadena base 64 de nuevo a un arreglo de bytes:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Firma))]
public IHttpActionResult PostFirma([FromBody] FirmaModel firmaModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    // convertir cadena a arreglo de bytes
    var firmaArray = Convert.FromBase64String(firmaModel.FirmaDigital);

    // crear objeto
    var firma = new Firma {  idFirma =  firmaModel.IdFirma, firmaDigital = firmaArray  };

    db.Firmas.Add(firma);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = firma.idFirma }, firma);
}
```

Comment: Estimado @Lobos, me muestra error al almacenar la conversión en Android en el objeto.                      
Firma firma = new Firma(); firma.setFirmaDigital(Base64.encodeToString(mSig.getBytes()));

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Cannot resolve method encodeToString(byte[])

Comment: Cierto, faltaba un parámetro en el método. Ya lo agregué.

Comment: Estimado muchísimas gracias. Funciono a la perfección.